# trend for / in / of?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, collocation

Please refer to the diagram shown below.

[image: world food and oil prices]

Which preposition is should be used in this sentence?

> The trends [**for / in / of**]  both commodities are very similar.

I have looked up my Oxford dictionary and I found only "in" might be appropriate. However, I saw a prestigious teacher use "for" instead. Thus, I am a bit confused.

Comment: A case might be made for each of the three. Have a look at this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trends+in+both%2Ctrends+for+both%2Ctrends+of+both&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrends%20in%20both%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrends%20for%20both%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrends%20of%20both%3B%2Cc0) and click the links at the bottom to look for examples.

Comment: pls spl out ur wds

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue, I found this on [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trend). This is inline with the previous comment that a case could be made for each use:

> Trend
>   *noun*
>
> 1 : a line of general direction or movement [the trend **of** the coast turned toward the west] 
>   2 a : a prevailing tendency or inclination : DRIFT [current trends **in** education]
>      b : a general movement : SWING [the trend **toward** suburban living]
>      c : a current style or preference : VOGUE [new fashion trends]
>      d : a line of development : APPROACH 
>   3 : the general movement over time of a statistically detectable change also : a statistical curve reflecting such a change

Answer (score 0):

The trends **for** both commodities are very similar. = in respect of

The trends **in** both commodities are very similar. = in the case of; bounded by.

The trends **of** both commodities are very similar. = associated with